# Moq with Type.Missing parameters

Tags: c#, excel, moq, excel-interop

I am trying to mock Excel's Interop Names.Add()
It looks like this

```
Name Add(object Name = Type.Missing, object RefersTo = Type.Missing, object Visible = Type.Missing, object MacroType = Type.Missing, object ShortcutKey = Type.Missing, object Category = Type.Missing, object NameLocal = Type.Missing, object RefersToLocal = Type.Missing, object CategoryLocal = Type.Missing, object RefersToR1C1 = Type.Missing, object RefersToR1C1Local = Type.Missing);
```

I am trying to use Callback() to set up local collections to prove Add() was called correctly:

```
names.Setup(n => n.Add(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>(), Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)).Callback(
                    (object name, object r, object a, object b, object c, object d, object e, object f, object g, object h, object i) =>
{
    nameList.Add((string)name);
    rangeList.Add(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)r).Formula);
});
```

This works fine to "setup" but when I call it with

```
var result = names.Add(name, cell, true);
```

This throws an exception

"Additional information: Missing parameter does not have a default value."

```
 at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at Moq.Extensions.InvokePreserveStack(Delegate del, Object[] args) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Extensions.cs:line 108
```

I have tried the setup with nulls instead of Type.Missing as well, and it will work but only if I explicitly use

```
var result = names.Add(name, cell, true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

But I don't want to change my real code like this just for unit test hell.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use `It.Any` for all the arguments when setting up member for test

Comment: Should've mentioned, I did it that way 1st - same problem with the "Missing parameter does not have a default value" when names.Add() is actually called

Comment: In fact, even using It.Any and populating the rest of the names.Add() call with Type.Missing doesn't work.
Nulls in names.Add() will work with null or It.Any in the Setup() call.
The issue is really that I don't want to change the names.Add() to have all those nulls just for testing

Comment: So I just ended up extending Names interface, and make Add() and mocking this class as what is returned from Names object in workbook.Names.
Lets me unit test w/o changing the code, but still seems to be a bug in the moq framework

Comment: Hi @Dreamer, I am experiencing a similar issue on mocking a call to Word interop ([Range.GoTo(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.goto?view=word-pia)). If I understand your approach, you created a new interface defining your desired overload of Add() and a class implementing it by redirecting the calls then to the original interface?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with MS Access's Interop Application.Run() method.

Try using

```
object missingArg = Missing.Value;
```

in place of Type.Missing.